# SQL Server : code works fine as a query but getting timeout expired error as a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, timeout, execution

This code works fine as a query but If I want to save it as a view I'm getting an error

> Sql server execution error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Code:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.Kampanya, dbo.MFRaporSrg.[BM Adı], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[DEPO ADI], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[Müşteri Adı] AS MusteriAdi, 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[Ürün Adı], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[SATIŞ ADET], dbo.MFRaporSrg.SonucMF, 
    COUNT(dbo.MFRaporSrg.SonucMF) AS SaySonucMF, 
    dbo.UrunFiyatTbl.Fiyat
FROM            
    dbo.MFRaporSrg 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.UrunFiyatTbl ON dbo.MFRaporSrg.Kampanya = dbo.UrunFiyatTbl.KampanyaAdi 
                     AND dbo.MFRaporSrg.[Ürün Adı] = dbo.UrunFiyatTbl.UrunAdi
GROUP BY 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.Kampanya, dbo.MFRaporSrg.[BM Adı], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[DEPO ADI], dbo.MFRaporSrg.[Müşteri Adı], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[Ürün Adı], dbo.MFRaporSrg.[SATIŞ ADET], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.SonucMF, dbo.UrunFiyatTbl.Fiyat
ORDER BY 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.Kampanya, dbo.MFRaporSrg.[BM Adı],  
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[DEPO ADI], MusteriAdi, dbo.MFRaporSrg.[Ürün Adı], 
    dbo.MFRaporSrg.[SATIŞ ADET]
```

I tried to increase timeout at Tools-> Options -> Designers -> Table and Database Designers -> transaction timeout after 65535(max) but still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ORDER BY Statement and the TOP 100 PERCENT and then create your view.

You can select an ordered list from the view after it's created by doing:

```
SELECT 
   something
FROM 
   View
ORDER BY
   something
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't use order by without "select top 100 percent". Finally I found a solution for timeout expired error. Run -> regedit -> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\DataProject\SQLQueryTimeout Changed Value 30 to 300 and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Run -> regedit -> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\DataProject\SQLQueryTimeout Changed Value 30 to 300 and problem solved.